# Automount USB flash drive on Raspbian Stretch lite with udev

Tags: raspbian, mount, udev, automount

I'm using a udev rule to automount USB flash drives on my Raspberry Pi. I found [this solution](https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/auto-mounting-usb-storage/) few months ago and I worked very well until I start using **Raspbian Stretch lite**.

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
# Import FS infos
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"
# Get a label if present, otherwise specify one
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"
# Global mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime"
# Filesystem-specific mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat|ntfs", ENV{mount_options}="\$env{mount_options},utf8,gid=100,umask=002"
# Mount the device
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/usbstick", RUN+="/bin/mount -o \$env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/usbstick"
# Clean up after removal
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/usbstick", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/usbstick"
# Exit
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

And here is what I see in `dmesg`

```
[  524.042731] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[  524.174634] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
[  524.174649] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  524.174658] usb 1-1.4: Product: Flash Disk
[  524.174666] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: USB
[  524.174674] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: SCY0000000105542
[  524.175515] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  524.175994] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
[  525.399056] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB      Flash Disk       1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  525.399986] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  525.400243] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 15974400 512-byte logical blocks: (8.18 GB/7.62 GiB)
[  525.401232] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  525.401259] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  525.401948] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[  525.401965] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  525.415578]  sda: sda1
[  525.418642] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Do anybody has a similar solution that works with Raspbian Stretch lite?

Comment: Hopefully whoever down voted your question will change their mind. This seems like a valid programming question for raspbian and udev programming. I wrote something on another forum here for automounting and running a bash file using udev - I'll see if I can find the link.

Comment: Let me know if this helps at all - I wrote [this piece of code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134233/raspberry-pi-headless-server-using-bash-and-usb-automounting) in Code Review for Jessie Lite awhile ago. It uses a shell script and uDev rules.

Comment: @dbmitch thank you for your comments. I finally identified the problem but I still don't understand why. I must create the directory manually `sudo /bin/mkdir -p /media/usbstick`. It seems it doesn't work from _udev rule_